# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'RSI_RESULT' before initialization

Tags: angular, undefined-reference, ngx-charts

What I want to do is creating an array using `setRsi()` function, then plotting it using `doOutput()` function that opens a new dialog for showing the result using `ngg-charts` component.

This is `flow.component.ts` file and `setRsi()` method is a click-event trigger function:

```
export class FlowComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  setRsi(selectedValue){
    console.log('The RSI period is:' , selectedValue);
    periodd = selectedValue;
    this.label2 = ' نام اندیکاتور:  RSI';
    this.label3 = ' دوره زمانی: ' + periodd + 'روزه';
    rsi_result = rsi({period: periodd, values: pricess});
    console.log('The RSI result is:' ,  rsi_result);
  }

  doOutput(){
    this.dialog.open(NgxChartsComponent ) ; //, {width: '500px', height: '500px'});

  }
}

export const RSI_RESULT = rsi_result;
export const MACD_RESULT = macd_result;
```

`doOutput()` is also another click-event function that causes the error message.

I can see `rsi_result` or `macd_result` in my console when I click on related buttons, but when I want to export and import then in `ngx-chart.component.ts` file to plot the data, I will get the following error:

`ngx-charts.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

import {MACD_RESULT , RSI_RESULT} from '../flow/flow.component';
import {Mellat, Khodro, Shepna} from '../shared/stock_inf';
import { NewsComponent } from '../news/news.component';

var mellat = Mellat;
var khodro = Khodro;
var shepna = Shepna;

 var macd_result = MACD_RESULT;
 var rsi_result = RSI_RESULT;

console.log(rsi_result);


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ngx-charts',
  templateUrl: './ngx-charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ngx-charts.component.scss']
})



export class NgxChartsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NgxChartsComponent>) { }



  // data goes here
public single = [
  {
    "name": " درصد سود",
    "value": 69
  },
  {
    "name": " درصد زیان",
    "value": 31
  },

];



// LENGTH = RSI_RESULT.length;
 newArray = rsi_result.map((e, i) => ({
  "name": (i + 1).toString(),
  "value": e,
}));

newArray2 = mellat.map((e, i) => ({
  "name": (i + 1).toString(),
  "value": e,
}));


public multi = [
  {
    "name": "RSI",
    "series": this.newArray
  },

  {
    "name": "Mellat",
    "series": this.newArray2
  },

];

//{name: (i + 1).toString(), value: e.toString()}



  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options for the chart
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'زمان';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'قیمت';
  timeline = true;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

  //pie
  showLabels = true;
  explodeSlices = false;
  doughnut = false;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
main.js:5431 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'RSI_RESULT' before initialization
    at Module.RSI_RESULT (main.js:5431)
    at Module../src/app/ngx-charts/ngx-charts.component.ts (ngx-charts.component.ts:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/flow/flow.component.ts (main.js:5440)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
```

I think there is a problem through passing `RSI_RESULT` and `MACD_RESULT` and I also get the following warnings:

```
client:126 [WDS] Warnings while compiling.
warnings @ client:126
(anonymous) @ socket.js:47
sock.onmessage @ SockJSClient.js:58
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone-evergreen.js:1191
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
client:135 Circular dependency detected:
src\app\flow\flow.component.ts -> src\app\ngx-charts\ngx-charts.component.ts -> src\app\flow\flow.component.ts
warnings @ client:135
(anonymous) @ socket.js:47
sock.onmessage @ SockJSClient.js:58
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone-evergreen.js:1191
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
client:135 Circular dependency detected:
src\app\ngx-charts\ngx-charts.component.ts -> src\app\flow\flow.component.ts -> src\app\ngx-charts\ngx-charts.component.ts
```

> EDIT:

If I put my variables inside my class like below:

```
export class NgxChartsComponent implements OnInit {


  mellat = Mellat;
  khodro = Khodro;
  shepna = Shepna;

  macd_result = MACD_RESULT;
  rsi_result = RSI_RESULT;
...
}
```

I will get the following new errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at new NgxChartsComponent (ngx-charts.component.ts:45)
    at createClass (core.js:27865)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:27685)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:38315)
    at createRootView (core.js:38187)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:39716)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:38953)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:26827)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:22791)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:26983)
View_NgxChartsComponent_Host_0 @ NgxChartsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19436
logError @ core.js:39651
handleError @ core.js:9162
dispatchEvent @ core.js:25822
(anonymous) @ core.js:37030
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:1789
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:34182
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
NgxChartsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

Comment: First it's not good to use var, use const. then how are you accessing rsi_result out of your class? in line ```export const RSI_RESULT = rsi_result;```

Comment: @FatemeFazli: You mean exports outside of the class don't have access to variables inside of the class?

Comment: Of course, not.

Comment: @FatemeFazli: I searched for my problem and think I must use services to pass variables from one component to another.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to put all your variables

```
var mellat = Mellat;
var shepna = Shepna;
var macd_result = MACD_RESULT;
var rsi_result = RSI_RESULT;
```

inside the export class block without using var keyword like below.

```
export class NgxChartsComponent implements OnInit {

mellat = Mellat;
shepna = Shepna;
macd_result = MACD_RESULT;
rsi_result = RSI_RESULT;
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NgxChartsComponent>) { }
}
```

Because using var will create a global variable which you won't get in "this" object

Comment: I have edited my question. Please read the EDIT part. Thank you!